# Why does the "(x,y)" product disappear when thought of as a subset of the quotient?

Tags: linear-algebra

Sorry I can't think of a good title.

Let $G$ be a group and $K = K_1 \times K_2$ where $K_1, K_2 \subset G$.

The product $K_1 \times K_2$ denotes $(k_1, k_2) \in K_1 \times K_2$.

But when we consider as a quotient $G/K$, we think of $K_1 \times K_2 \subset G$? Why?

For example, let $U(n)$ denote the unitary group. We think of $\frac{U(3)}{U(1) \times U(1) }$ as  $\frac{G}{K_1 \times K_2}$. Normally we think of $U(1) \times U(1)$ as $(u_1, u_2)$ where $u_1, u_2$  are unitary matrices, but as a subgroup, this is actually the block matrix? $\begin{pmatrix}
U(1) & 0 & 0 \\ 
 0& U(1) &0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

So how did the pair product turn into a block matrix?

Answer (score 1):

This is a special case of notation, because mathematicians are lazy. $U(1)$ is not actually a subgroup of $U(3)$, neither is $U(1) \times U(1)$, but we still write $U(1) \times U(1)$ to refer to a particular subgroup of $U(3)$, namely the one that is most obviously isomorphic to $U(1) \times U(1)$: the group of the form
$$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}u_1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & u_2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \in U(3): (u_1), (u_2)\in U(1)\right\}.$$

Note that this laziness is to be used with caution, since specifying a group and an isomorphism class of subgroup does not uniquely determine the factor group. For example $C_8 \times C_4$ has many different subgroups isomorphic to $C_2$, some of which induce different quotients than others. So only use this notation when the induced quotient is unique, or when it is otherwise obvious which subgroup you mean.

Comment: Sorry, but what is the definition of $\times $ then? Is this not the usual direct product?

Comment: It is the usual direct product.

Comment: But you are saying it is also denoting a special group of the form....

Comment: It does not denote, it *means* a special subgroup of that form. Just like the phrase "a special subgroup of that form" does not *denote* any particular mathematical group, but you still know which group and subgroup I'm talking about.

Comment: Let $A$ denote the special diagonal subgroup as you have written. You are saying $U(1) \times U(1) = \{ (u_1, u_2) \} \approx A$ by linear isomorphism of vector spaces?

Comment: No, because neither is a vector space. I'm saying they're isomorphic as groups.

Comment: Excuse me, you are correct. The $0$ matrix does not belong in this space.